# Scrollbar is visible and slidable, but does not function as a scrollbar

Tags: python-2.7, canvas, matplotlib, tkinter, scrollbar

Stackoverflow,

So I am relatively new to programming in general and am working on a little project that involves livestreaming data through matplotlib into a gui, which I have more or less created using Tkinter. Anyway, the number of graphs I have to output ranges from 1-18, depending on the options chosen by the user. Given the potentially large number of graphs, I needed scrollbars, for which I have shamelessly taken the code from another stackoverflow post and attempted to modify to fit my program. The code is as follows:

```
    #Create popup window for graph display
tlg = Toplevel()
tlg.geometry('400x400')
tlg.title('Live Data Stream')

#Set frame for canvas
frame=Frame(tlg,width=300,height=300)
frame.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=True) #allows dynamic resizing of frame/scrollbar

#Create a canvas on which to play scrollbar widget
canvas=Canvas(frame,bg='#FFFFFF',width=300,height=300,scrollregion=(0,0,500,500))

#Add horizontal and vertical scrollbars
hbar=Scrollbar(frame,orient=HORIZONTAL)
hbar.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X) 
hbar.config(command=canvas.xview)
vbar=Scrollbar(frame,orient=VERTICAL)
vbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
vbar.config(command=canvas.yview)

#Pack and implement canvas
canvas.config(width=300,height=300,scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
canvas.config(xscrollcommand=hbar.set, yscrollcommand=vbar.set)
canvas.pack(side=LEFT,expand=True,fill=BOTH)

#######################------- MatPlotLib Graph Creation --------#######################
tlglabel1 = Label(canvas, text='LIVE DATA STREAM', font=('VERDANA',12,'bold'),
                  bg='white').grid(row=0,padx=5,pady=5)

quadl = plt.figure(1,figsize=(5,5))
plt.clf()
quadlx=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
quadly=[3,4,5,2,3,4,1,6]
plt.plot(quadlx,quadly)
plt.gcf().canvas.draw()
canvasql = FigureCanvasTkAgg(quadl,canvas)
canvasql.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1,column=1)
toolbarql = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvasql,canvas)
toolbarql.grid(row=2,column=1)

quadr = plt.figure(2,figsize=(5,5))
plt.clf()
quadrx=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
quadry=[3,4,5,2,3,4,1,6]
plt.plot(quadrx,quadry)
plt.gcf().canvas.draw()
canvasqr = FigureCanvasTkAgg(quadr,canvas)
canvasqr.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1,column=2,padx=10)
toolbarqr = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvasqr,canvas)
toolbarqr.grid(row=2,column=2,padx=10)
```

I have added in two test graphs just to test the functionality of the scrollbar, which, after testing, fails to do anything. I honestly don't know what to do. I tried replacing the first `scrollregion=(0,0,500,500)` with `scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all')` because every other scrollbar code had that, but then it deleted my canvas and removed my scrollbars completely. I tried replacing `hbar=Scrollbar(frame,orient=HORIZONTAL)` with `hbar=Scrollbar(canvas,orient=HORIZONTAL)`, thinking that the scrollbar needs to shift the canvas, but that just crashed the program. I attempted to change the `command = canvas.xview` and `command=canvas.yview` to `frame` instead by recommendation of another forum, and that failed. Sooo, I'm stuck.

Comment: This simplest solution is to install the Python Metawidgets (Pmw) extension and use its built in ScrolledFrame http://pmw.sourceforge.net/doc/ScrolledFrame.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read about [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)s.  Half your posted code is irrelevant to the question and the other half is incomplete.

A scrolled frame needs an outer frame that contains a canvas and one or two linked scrollbars and an inner frame placed on the canvas so that it moves with the canvas.  Either could be a LabelFrame.  Here is the code from 3.5 idlelib.configDialog for a vertical scrolled frame.  A horizontal scrollbar would be easy to add.  Notice that it has a couple of methods to keep sizes synchronized.

```
class VerticalScrolledFrame(Frame):
    """A pure Tkinter vertically scrollable frame.

    * Use the 'interior' attribute to place widgets inside the scrollable frame
    * Construct and pack/place/grid normally
    * This frame only allows vertical scrolling
    """
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kw):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kw)

        # create a canvas object and a vertical scrollbar for scrolling it
        vscrollbar = Scrollbar(self, orient=VERTICAL)
        vscrollbar.pack(fill=Y, side=RIGHT, expand=FALSE)
        canvas = Canvas(self, bd=0, highlightthickness=0,
                        yscrollcommand=vscrollbar.set, width=240)
        canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=TRUE)
        vscrollbar.config(command=canvas.yview)

        # reset the view
        canvas.xview_moveto(0)
        canvas.yview_moveto(0)

        # create a frame inside the canvas which will be scrolled with it
        self.interior = interior = Frame(canvas)
        interior_id = canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=interior, anchor=NW)

        # track changes to the canvas and frame width and sync them,
        # also updating the scrollbar
        def _configure_interior(event):
            # update the scrollbars to match the size of the inner frame
            size = (interior.winfo_reqwidth(), interior.winfo_reqheight())
            canvas.config(scrollregion="0 0 %s %s" % size)
        interior.bind('<Configure>', _configure_interior)

        def _configure_canvas(event):
            if interior.winfo_reqwidth() != canvas.winfo_width():
                # update the inner frame's width to fill the canvas
                canvas.itemconfigure(interior_id, width=canvas.winfo_width())
        canvas.bind('<Configure>', _configure_canvas)

        return
```

Comment: Terry, other than the fact that I left out my imports and tlg.mainloop() at the end, I don't understand what about the mcve's that I'm missing. The code I provided contained my problem, which was the scrollbar code that I had written, as well as a method to test whether or not the scrollbar worked using matplotlib figures since I read that you cannot scroll a blank slate. Regardless, I have read the mcve's and will keep that in mind. As far as the the answer goes, I think I understand. I'll give Curly Joe's response a shot, first, as Pmw ScrolledFrame seems to be easier.

Comment: I am assuming that you want a scrollable frame because a) you  want to put each graph on its own canvas rather than putting up to 18 graphs on one canvas and b) you want to grid (or place) the canvases on the frame. ... Without the complete code, I cannot copy, paste, and run.   With a matlab import and matlab code, I also cannot run.  To test scrolling, you only need, for instance, to add a Text() and insert something like `("now is the " * 10 + '\n' + "time for all " * 10 + '\n') * 50"` that will make correct operation visible.